# unsigned long(u32_t) conversion to string array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, hex

in my quest( still starting :) ) to be better at programming I've stumbled upon something that I just cannot answer.

I was tasked to convert binary/hex data (in an array) to string array. So far I've only managed to convert and print the "MSB"s of the hex data.

Here is my current code. Constructive criticism is highly appreciated :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;  

    unsigned long rawdata[] ={0x60,0x100,'\0'};

    char stringForRawdata[250];

    char finalString[250];

    while(i<2)
    {
        sprintf(stringForRawdata,"%lx",*(rawdata+i));

        //sprintf(finalString,"%s",stringForRawdata);

        finalString[i] = *(stringForRawdata);

        printf("\nfinalString[%d] = %s",i,finalString+i);

        printf("\nrawdata = %lx for i = %d\n",*(rawdata+i),i); 

        i = i+1;    

    }
    printf("\n stringForRawdata = %s\n",stringForRawdata);
    printf("\n\n finalString array is %s\n",finalString);
 }
```

input is the `unsigned long rawdata[] ={0x60,0x100,'\0'};`

expected output is a string array `{60,100,\0}` or `{0x60,0x100,\0}`

the problem is that I can only get the leftmost digit to my string array.

Comment: IF you want a review, you should post this under Code Review.

Comment: Give us the inputs and outputs you are expecting.

Comment: I've edited my post ^^

Comment: `std::to_string`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem starts with the line

```
finalString[i] = *(stringForRawdata);
```

finalString is an array of char so finalString[i] is a single character. So you are only setting a single character in finalString each time round the loop. You need to concatenate the rawdata strings into finalString using strcat.

Comment: Thanks Tim! though I dint get what I really wanted I learned something new. Anyhow, now I can put the hex array to string array, however, each digit is assigned to each element. so if my hex array has 2 elements, my string array gets 4.

 I think I can work on this, but additional information/help would still be great!